# Sharepoint designer workflow based on secondary list

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a main list with field "site" and a secondary list with field "site" and "manager name". There are 10 sites and each have manager name. I have created lookup field site in main list and value is taking from secondary list. When user select any site mail need to be trigger to its correspondent manager. Like secondary list has value Site = AMS and Manager = XYZ

When I fill the main list and select site = AMS , a mail need to be trigger to xyz.
How can I acheive this using sharepoint designer workflow.

Do I need to configure secondary list with lookup field

Answer (score 0):

Having already created a lookup column on the main list pointing to the secondary list, now creating a workflow to retrieve the email information from the second list is trivial.

Add an action "Email these users", then for the TO field, select "Workflow lookup for a user", then see the screenshot below on how to configure the lookup retrieval:

[image]

Comment: I cannot see screenshot. Can you send me screenshot on brishalkumar@gmail.com

Comment: @user21081 check your inbox